# Set up remote logging with Syslogd

Tags: syslog

How do you configure the syslogd service to listen on UDP port 514?
Do you specify the port with the -r option in the /etc/sysconfig/syslog file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following two options in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Also, regular syslog doesn't have this capability. It has to be rsyslog which is usually used when this is necessary.